# Using Microsoft.aspNet.Identity 2.2.1 how can I force a password change?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've got an ASP.Net MVC website that I am using MS ASPNet Identity 2.2.1 for security. I am preloading customer names from a list and would like to set their account to force them to reset their password on first login.

Is there a way to do this with the Identity Core?

Comment: Are you sending the temp password and you want to invalidate it after first login?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.